# Converting some columns into indicator variables after grouping by another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm creating a *k-nn* model and I need to reorganize my dataset into a nice euclidean vectors.

My dataset looks like the one below

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'orderID': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                     'productID': [1, 3, 1, 2]})
```

which yields

```
   orderID  productID
0        1          1
1        1          3
2        2          1
3        2          2
```

I would like to group my data by *orderID* and then create a vector which would store the information the products which were bought in each order. So I need something like this dataframe

```
   orderID  prod_1  prod_2  prod_3
0        1       1       0       1
1        2       1       1       0
```

Is there any "built-in" method to achieve that?

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [84]: data['prod_name'] = 'prod_' + data.productID.astype('str')
In [105]: data.pivot_table(index='orderID', columns='prod_name', values='productID', aggfunc=len).fillna(0).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)                                                         
Out[105]: 
   orderID  prod_1  prod_2  prod_3
0        1     1.0     0.0     1.0
1        2     1.0     1.0     0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use your `pd.pivot_table` with `len` and `reset_index` to return your orderID if you don't want it as an index:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['orderID'], columns=['productID'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```